# Extract text from every three lines using Windows

Tags: java, bitcoin

I have a HUGE text file with details of my site users. (11GB+).
It's built like that:

```
Email: example@gmail.com
Address: 1blahblahblahblah (Bitcoin Address).
Password: blahblahblah
```

Each of the details in a seperate line. (no spaces between them).

The detail I need is the Bitcoin address. I need them orginized in a text file, one after another.

Simply, I need a batch/java/whatever script that skips the first line, takes the Bitcoin address and puts it in a file, and then skips another line.. continuously.

I need the exported BTC addresses in a list, one address for each line.

The output I need:

1Exampleexampleexample

1Exampleexampleexample

1Exampleexampleexample

1Exampleexampleexample

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a PowerShell script that will fetch every 2nd line (in groups of 3) and remove the superfluous text and the beginning and end of that line:

```
$fileToProcess = "C:\users\jsmith\Dropbox\neat scripts\userInfo.txt"
$fileToWrite = "C:\users\jsmith\Dropbox\neat scripts\bitcoin.txt" 
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fileToProcess)
$lineCount = 1
try {
        for(;;) {                
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
            if ($line -eq $null) { break }
            # process the line
            if ($lineCount -eq 2) {  
                $line = $line -replace "Address: "
                $line = $line -replace ' \(Bitcoin Address\).'
                Add-Content $fileToWrite ("`n"+$line)    
            }

            $lineCount = $lineCount+1
            if ($lineCount -gt 3) { $lineCount = 1}
        }
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
    }
```

Per my normal caveat, do not test this without making a backup of the file you're parsing. I have tested this on my machine (with a much smaller file than the one you're parsing) and it shouldn't change the input file, however, your mileage may vary!

Comment: I'm not sure how to run PowerShell scripts. I get this error using the PowerShell terminal: http://i.gyazo.com/36b80fdd2f7f37f6e7dfe1bb4d334022.png

Comment: Your problem is that your PowerShell execution policy is set to restricted. (See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) for details regarding PowerShell execution policies.) Close any PowerShell windows you currently have open. Search for PowerShell on the Start Menu, right click on it, and `Run as Administrator...` and launch it as an admin. Then type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` Assuming it runs ok, you can run the script I provided. (The easiest way is probably to copy and paste my code into PowerShell ISE and run it from there.)

Comment: Okay. it did work this time, but the output included the "Address:" and I don't need it, I need only the addresses. Thanks for helping me out man

Comment: My assumption was wrong about your file actually having the words "Address: " in front of each line. I will edit the script to account for this.

Comment: Should work now.

Comment: Tried to run the new script and got this error: http://i.gyazo.com/1a2a7b220d8ac199aa1355742f093589.png Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: Did you change the two variables for the input and output files at the top to match your actual files? Otherwise, I don't really know what the error is about.

Comment: the source file was opened in another program. issues fixed and your script works like a charm. Thanks A LOT man! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Make sure to select the question as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I extract text from every third line?

> The detail I need is the Bitcoin address. I need them orginized in a text file, one after another.

You can use `findstr`.

Note:

- I don't have an 11GB file to test against.

Test data:

```
Email: example@gmail.com
Address: address 1 (Bitcoin Address).
Password: blahblahblah
Email: example@gmail.com
Address: address 2 (Bitcoin Address).
Password: blahblahblah
Email: example@gmail.com
Address: address 3 (Bitcoin Address).
Password: blahblahblah
```

Command:

```
findstr Address data.txt > address.out
```

Output:

```
C:\test>type address.out
Address: address 1 (Bitcoin Address).
Address: address 2 (Bitcoin Address).
Address: address 3 (Bitcoin Address).
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Answer (score 0):

[FINDSTR - Search for strings in files](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html).

```
findstr /I /C:"Address:" "HUGE text file.txt">"BTC addresses"
```

Next resource (required reading) (`>`, `>>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)